# living web page elements

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a simple rails app with a model `Task`, which has 10 rows. It does not matter what's inside this table. On the `index` page I can see all 10 elements and I need to arrange them in proper sequence, when I did this, I should see a message "Done".

If I understand correctly this should be implemented in javascript, because page should not be reloaded, right?

I want to be able to rearrange the elements via drag and drop.

How I can realize that function?

Comment: What are the elements? We'll need to know in order to tell what the "proper sequence" of them should be.

Comment: `elements` is rows from `Task` table. 1 `element` is some `div` on web page. I search in internet and I see that a good solution to this problem is jquery library(Drag & Drop). I understood correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with here -> http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

You can sort and its quite simple as there great examples on the site how to do this and hook into events.